# Calling template inside template angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tracking and nutrition templates are called like below:

```
.state('app.tracking', {
    url: '/tracking',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tracking.html',
        controller: 'TrackingCtrl'
      }
    }
})

  .state('app.nutrition', {
      url: '/nutrition',
      views: {
          'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/nutrition.html',
              controller: 'NutritionCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
```

When tracking route is called tracking.html will be displayed.
I also want to display the nutrition.html inside the tracking.html when called.

So, in tracking.html I have included code like below:

```
  <ng-include src="templates/nutrition.html"></ng-include>
```

expecting that nutrition.html is also displayed inside tracking.html when my route is tracking.html.
But not working. Anything missing here?

Comment: how you can named a directive with 'tracking.html'? what is your error msg?

Comment: tracking.html is a template..not directive..have edited the question..if that helps...there is no error message in console...

Comment: Have you checked the path?

Comment: yes..path is correct...previously it was throwing error on path..but i fixed it..no errors in console...

Comment: Hi, try wrapping your url in a single quote inside the double .  like this

   `<ng-include src=" 'templates/nutrition.html' "></ng-include>`

Comment: wrapping in single quotes working..thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your URL in single quotes.
`<ng-include src=" 'templates/nutrition.html' "></ng-include>`